# What is the most efficient way to implement a Redshift merge/upsert operation

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am in the process of writing a custom upsert function for a specific use case for a redshift table. On their docs, AWS suggests [two methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html#merge-method-replace-existing-rows) which i'm drawing inspiration from. Here is what i want to accomplish:

- Insert any new rows to an existing table, but only if they don't already exist.
- There is never a need to delete or modify an existing row (for my use case)

I have so far come up with two separate ways to do this, but I'm wondering what the tradeoffs of each could be

1. using an `EXCEPT` query for insertion of only new rows from a temp table:

```
    insert into persisted_table (
      select * 
      from temp_table 
      except 
      select * 
      from persisted_table
     );
```

2. store results of a`UNION ALL` query on temp table with persisted table, and use that as the persisted table

```
    insert into new_table (
      select * 
      from temp_table 
      union
      select * 
      from persisted_table
     );
     
     alter table persisted_table rename to old_perisisted_table_marked_for_deletion;
     alter table new_table rename to persisted_table;
```

I'm aware that union all is slow and generally not recommended for bulk/large scale operations. Apart from that though are there any arguments that could influence this decision?

Comment: I'm almost certain you want UNION not UNION ALL in the second solution (since UNION ALLskips the DISTINCT part). As for the question itself I would expect the first solution to be faster (especially if both table share their distkey and sortkey (and are both sorted)), but there is no way to be sure without trying them both out.

Comment: @Marth thank you for pointing that out, i did mean to use union and not union all. updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

The first advise I'd give is to remember that Redshift is a cluster.  Whatever process you select, if the data is large, you will want the comparison to determine if the row already exists to stay "on node".  You will want the tables in questions to be distributed by the same key.

Next I would think about what the indexes are into the data.  The processes you laid out will compare all columns when comparing.  Is this needed?  If a subset of columns can be the key this can make things more efficient.

```
insert into persisted_table (
  select * from temp_table a left join persisted_table b on {keys}
  where a.keys is null );
```

Hopefully these aspects will help your decision process

Comment: May I ask what to do with multiple unique columns from source?

Comment: This will be unique to your data model but a common feature in most is that there is a few id columns (and an upsert timestamp) that uniquely identifies each entry.  With this you just need to ensure that the few columns don't match to insert or if they do then delete existing first.  Make sure you staging table is distributed the same way as the target table.  If you can restrict which range of the target table needs to be compared this will speed things up as well.

Comment: delete rows from the target that have matching keys to anything in the staging table.  insert the staging table onto target.  Do all of this in a transaction block.  But be sure that you have all the columns needed to uniquely identify rows or you will lose data.